# Get source URL or image name from canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

I'm making a chrome extension and I need to find the source url of a image inside a canvas or the image name. I need this because the image name is the id of the item I want to catch with the extension and I can't figure how to get one of the two.

I already tried to getDataUlr() from the canvas but this is just the image on a big string and nothing referencing the id that I need.

It's this even possible?

Best regards and thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The contents of a Canvas are not necessarily coming from a source URL image, it could be a composite of many images or it could just be generated dynamically.

See the canvas on this example below there is not source image, what we see in the canvas is all drawn using javascript, and since I'm using `Math.random` the image is different on every run.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 170;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(85, 85)

for (var i = 0; i < 360; i += 2) {
  var angle = i * Math.PI / 90;
  var x = Math.cos(angle) * 40;
  var y = Math.sin(angle) * 40;

  ctx.beginPath();
  var v = Math.random() + 1;
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x * v, y * v)
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

For your needs, if you can guarantee that the contents of the canvas are not changing `getDataUlr()` is your friend, get that save it and then you can provide your own url.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. The way that you say to use the getDataUrl() will provide a link of my own and I will not be able to find the origin link.
I know that the image is being rendered from a URL source because if I got to the network tab I see that the image have a link and them it should be rendered to a canvas.

The idea here it's not generate a canvas with a image I have, but find out the URL source of the image rendered on the canvas

Comment: from a rendered canvas there is no way to backtrack the image shown, `getDataUlr` is your only option